# Медленная работа компьютера на Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, железо

Возникла следующая проблема: на ноутбуке установлена `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS` и в последнее время, стал ощущать тормознутость машины, а особенно при открытии новых вкладок в браузере `Chrome` (зависает), открытых вкладок максимум `10`, + работает редактор кода.

Раньше на машине стоял Виндовс и Линукс вместе и ноутбук работал хорошо. 
 `i3Core` - процесор, проделал кучу советов про повышении производительности `Ubuntu`, но стало только хуже.

В чем может быть проблема? 
На что обратить внимание?

Comment: Утилиты top htop помогут Вам определить узкое место.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Баллов на комментарий не хватает, поэтому отпишусь в виде ответа. У кого есть права - перенесите пожалуйста в комментарии.

Можно посмотреть вывод `smartctl --all /dev/sda` ? Утилита есть в пакете smartmontools.

С помощью MHDD тоже неплохо было бы прогнать.

Comment: smartctl --all /dev/sda
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [i686-linux-3.16.0-43-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Smartctl open device: /dev/sda failed: Permission denied

Comment: `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda`

P.S. http://xkcd.ru/149/

Comment: что из этого отчета показать?

Comment: Всё что между "Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds" и "SMART Error Log Version"

Comment: выложил в вопросе, но это жесть, очень много места занимает, и не знаю как лучше его разместить

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/ - скинь сюда. Или оформи как кусок кода. Второй вариант предпочтительнее.

Comment: закинул здесь: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12691992/

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29911/discussion-between-don-rumata-and-zorro).

Answer (score 1):

У меня дважды были подобные проблемы с Ubuntu. В первый раз дело было в драйвере для видеокарты Nvidia -- по умолчанию стоял не тот драйвер, нужно было поставить свежий. Во второй -- убился SSD-шник.

Answer (score 1):

1. Unity никогда не была легковесной
2. Кто вам сказал, что хром = lynx?
3. У меня KDE с хромиумом, Pentium Dual-Core E5500 @ 2.80GHz, 2 гб рам, нет видеокарты и разрешение 1600x1200. Падений ФПС не ощущаю!
4. У меня тоже была похожая проблема - лечения не знаю. После реинсталла пропала. Может, дебиан - твой выбор? Правда, шрифты немного багнутые в его GTK. Но я уже привык.

Comment: насчет легковесности согласен, но и тяжеловесом ее назвать не могу. С Линукс я давно, с Ubuntu более 2 лет, и повторюсь никаких багови замечаний не было